# UnixODBC [08004][unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified on Ubuntu VM

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, ubuntu-20.04, unixodbc, oracle18c

I have installed Oracle 18c express edition on my Windows 10 host, in which I have a pluggable database "xepdb1".

The database is up and running

Now I want to connect from a Ubuntu 20.04 VM using UnixODBC version 2.3.6.

I have installed Oracle instant client (Basic, ODBC Package, SQL*Plus Package) to /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5

I have set all environment variables,

```
ORACLE_HOME = opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5
TNS_ADMIN = opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5/network/admin
```

I could connect using sqlplus, and I wanted to test it using

```
isql -v OracleDSN
```

It gives [08004][unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified error.

**odbcinst -j**

```
unixODBC 2.3.6
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/amjad/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

**/home/amjad/.odbc.ini**

```
[OracleDSN]
AggregateSQLType = FLOAT
Application Attributes = T
Attributes = W
BatchAutocommitMode = IfAllSuccessful
BindAsFLOAT = F
CacheBufferSize = 20
CloseCursor = F
DisableDPM = F
DisableMTS = T
DisableRULEHint = T
Driver = Oracle18
DSN = OracleDSN
EXECSchemaOpt =
EXECSyntax = T
Failover = T
FailoverDelay = 10
FailoverRetryCount = 10
FetchBufferSize = 64000
ForceWCHAR = F
LobPrefetchSize = 8192
Lobs = T
Longs = T
MaxLargeData = 0
MaxTokenSize = 8192
MetadataIdDefault = F
QueryTimeout = T
ResultSets = T
ServerName = xepdb1
SQLGetData extensions = F
SQLTranslateErrors = F
StatementCache = F
Translation DLL =
Translation Option = 0
UseOCIDescribeAny = F
```

**/etc/odbcinst.ini**

```
[Oracle18]
Description     = Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle 18
Driver          = /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5//libsqora.so.18.1
Driver Logging = 7
UsageCount=1
FileUsage=1

[ODBC]
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/odbc.log
ForceTrace = Yes
Pooling = No
```

**/etc/odbc.ini**

```
[OracleDSN]
Application Attributes = T
Attributes = W
BatchAutocommitMode = IfAllSuccessful
BindAsFLOAT = F
CloseCursor = F
DisableDPM = F
DisableMTS = T
Driver = Oracle18   #the name from [Oracle] in /etc/odbcinst.ini
DSN = OracleDSN
EXECSchemaOpt =
EXECSyntax = T
Failover = T
FailoverDelay = 10
FailoverRetryCount = 10
FetchBufferSize = 64000
ForceWCHAR = F
Lobs = T
Longs = T
MaxLargeData = 0
MetadataIdDefault = F
QueryTimeout = T
ResultSets = T
ServerName = xepdb1    #servicename from tnsnames.ora
ORACLE_SID = xepdb1
SQLGetData extensions = F
Translation DLL =
Translation Option = 0
DisableRULEHint = T
StatementCache=F
CacheBufferSize=20
UseOCIDescribeAny=F
MaxTokenSize=8192
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-S1MEO2U.mshome.net)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-S1MEO2U.mshome.net)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
xepdb1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-S1MEO2U.mshome.net)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = xepdb1)
    )
  )
```

Thanks in advance, as I am stuck for two days now.

Comment: Maybe something in this will help: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/ora-12545-12541-12514-01017/

Comment: Don't set ORACLE_HOME when using Instant Client.  And you don't need to set TNS_ADMIN since you have set it to the directory that will be used by default.

Comment: Where is your tnsnames.ora located?  Did you put it in /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5/network/admin ?

Comment: yes it in /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5/network/admin